# Why doesn't max-width work on <table>s in IE7?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why does "max-width" not work on tables in Internet Explorer 7? `max-width` is available on other elements, and seems to work fine, but when applies to a table, I can't make it do anything, i.e. the `max-width` rule is simply ignored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background-color: Red; max-width: 1000px;">
        <table style="background-color: Green; max-width: 500px;">

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#" class="action view">View</a></td>
                    <td>7/20/2011</td>
                    <td>James Smith</td>
                    <td>345 NW 23rd Ave Gainesville, FL 32606</td>
                    <td>Alachua Blah blah sf jfh jsdhjs fjsh djkf sdjkhk</td>
                    <td>345621</td>
                    <td>Fred Smith</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, the table is properly constrained to 500px, and the text inside the cells breaks in appropriate ways (between words, just like you'd expect). In IE7 however, it's like the "no-wrap" rule has been applied. Each cell stretches out to its needed with, without trying to break text withing the cell, and the whole table simply stretches out to ignore the `max-width` rule.

How do I put `max-width` on a table in IE7? (It works fine in Firefox & IE8)

**What I've tried that doesn't work:**

```css
table { display: block; }

td { word-wrap: break-word; }

table { table-layout: fixed; }
```

Comment: Apparently IE7 does different things with `max-width` depending on the DTD: http://www.wileymedia.com/weblog/archives/2007/02/maxwidth_and_internet_explorer.html

Comment: Yeah I tried a few different DocTypes to no avail. That article is correct for general block-level elements, but it doesnt fix table.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The max-width property set for a table is ignored by WebKit browsers, both Chrome and Safari will render the table ignoring the max width as does IE7. I would recommend setting the max-width property to a wrapper element such as a `div`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/P5YPR/1/

Comment: +1 I'll always support cross-browser solutions over IE hacks. Good job.

Comment: @joao_pimentel Can you post a fiddle of your code that's not working? The above solution does work in IE7.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
table#my_table {
    max-width:500px;
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 500? "500px": "auto" );
}
```

Unfortunately this won't validate due to the `?`. The good news is since it's an IE-only solution you can simply do conditional elements when you create your `<body>` tag and setup IE-specific classes:

```
<!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie9 ie"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8 ie"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if IE 7]><body class="ie7 ie"><![endif]--> 
<!--[if lte IE 6]><body class="ie6 ie"><![endif]--> 
<![if !IE]><body><![endif]>
```

Now in your CSS:

```
table#my_table {
    width:500px;
    max-width:500px;
}

.ie7 table#my_table {
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 500? "500px": "auto" );
}
```

Comment: +1 Siiick. I don't usually recommend supporting IE<8 but this is solid.

Comment: This doesn't address WebKit. Safari and Chrome will still render the table ignoring the max-width property. If @Graham is truly concerned with cross browser compatibility, a wrapper element is much more elegant.

Comment: Your answer here works great, but I selected the Bjorn's as "correct" for my situation because the wrapper div is needed anyway really, and those expressions just creep me out. I like your bit about classes on the body with the IE comments though! Thanks!

Comment: Alien, I just noticed that Firefox doesn't render the [if !IE] section. Any ideas on how to write in the body tag in your example for non-IE browsers?